# Why does Math.Round behave differently between decimal and double

Tags: c#

I have these two tests, the first one passes and the second doesn't. Why?

```
//decimal
Assert.Equal(35.00M, Math.Round(34.995M, 2));

//double
Assert.Equal(35.00, Math.Round(34.995, 2));
```

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: because that is how floating point numbers work - do not ever expect them to be ***precise***. 35.995 cannot be _exactly_ represented as double, so the variable contains something _slightly smaller_ than that (34.994999999999997), which is why it's rounded _down_ (to 34.990000000000002).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is because of the nature of binary floating point numbers - most decimal numbers *cannot* be represented.

`34.995` is a perfect example - when assigned to a `double`-variable, the actual content will be `34.994999999999997` - which is a *tiny fraction* smaller.

as a result, it will be rounded *down* instead of up, to `34.99` (or, to be precise: `34.990000000000002`)

As a result, it will behave differently than expected when one is thinking in decimal. However, this is not a bug or something, but just a result of the way computers work, which one should be aware of.

> In general: one should *never* expect binary floating point numbers to be *precise*.

For more information, also see the [Floating Point Guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/)